# How to send original message payload to jms error queue

Tags: spring-integration

In the below example Spring Integration message flow, I need to be able to reprocess the original message.  One of the areas I have exceptions is in the transformer or in the call to the web service at the end.  So what I have seen so far is that once the payload is changed via a transformer or service, I can't roll back to the original message that was placed on the jms queue.  Is there a feature that would allow for me to send the original message to a different jms queue when exceptions occur?

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="Jms" 
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"      
        destination="queue" 
        channel="XMLChannel"
        error-channel="errorChannel"

        />  

    <int:channel id="XMLChannel"/>  

    <int:chain input-channel="XMLChannel" output-channel="ObjectChannel">
        <int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer id="defaultUnmarshaller" unmarshaller="xmlMarshaller"  />
    </int:chain>    

    <int:channel id="ObjectChannel"/>

    <int:chain id="transformerChain" input-channel="ObjectChannel" output-channel="post" >

        <int:filter ref="environmentFilter" />
        <int:filter ref="emailFilter" />

        <int:transformer ref="transformer" />

        <int:object-to-json-transformer object-mapper="objectMapperFactory" />

        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="content-type" value="application/json"></int:header>
        </int:header-enricher>

        <int-http:outbound-gateway 
            url="${url.${runtime.environment}}" 
            http-method="POST"
            expected-response-type="java.lang.String" 
            charset="UTF-8"
            reply-channel="post">
            <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <int:retry-advice max-attempts="3">
                    <int:exponential-back-off initial="5000"  multiplier="10.0" maximum="600000" />
                </int:retry-advice>
            </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>
    </int:chain>    

        <int:channel id="post"/>

        <int:logging-channel-adapter channel="post" level="INFO" log-full-message="true"/>

    <int:exception-type-router input-channel="addChannel" default-output-channel="errorChannel">
        <int:mapping />
    </int:exception-type-router>

    <int:channel id="errorChannel" />

    <int:chain input-channel="errorChannel">

        <int:transformer ref="errorTransformer"/>

    <!--        <int:object-to-json-transformer/>
     <int-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="xmlMarshaller"  /> -->
        <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="dcsConsumerAppointmentError"
            connection-factory="connectionFactory" destination="dcsConsumerAppointmentErrorQueue" />

    </int:chain>




@Transformer
    public Message<?> handleFailedOrder(Message<MessageHandlingException> message) throws JAXBException, IOException {

        log.info(message.getPayload().getMessage());

        JAXBElement<CustomerRequestVO> test = (JAXBElement<CustomerRequestVO>) message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload();

        String xml = jaxbMarshalToString(test.getValue());

        Message<?> messageOut = MessageBuilder.withPayload(xml).setHeader("Exception", message.getPayload().getMessage()).build();

        return messageOut;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear from your config what is `addChannel`, but as far as you use `error-channel="errorChannel"` the original message (I guess it is an XML) will be sended to the `errorChannel` as `failedMessage` of the `MessagingException`.

If your `handleFailedOrder` is a `<int:transformer ref="errorTransformer"/>` for the `errorChannel`, your `message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload()` should be an original XML, not unmarshaled `CustomerRequestVO`.

Another trick to keep track of the original `payload` is to put it to the `MessageHeaders` before further processing and transformation.

However, of course, you should keep in mind that the copy of the same mutable object will be changed everywhere, you will change its property once.

Comment: For some reason I'm not getting the original xml from message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload().

Comment: Well, switch on, please, DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` and show logs for the `errorChannel`, when you think you don't get correct XML payload.